# Replace & filter dataframe row values

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframe's one with expression and another with values. Dataframe 1 criteria column has value with column name of another dataframe. My need is to take each row values from Dataframe 2 and replace Dataframe 1 criteria without loop.

How should I do it in an optimized way ?

**DataFrame 1:**

```
     Criteria         point
0  chgdsl='10'         1
1  chgdt ='01022007'   2
3  chgdsl='9'          3
```

**DataFrame 2:**

```
      chgdsl            chgdt            chgname
  0     10              01022007          namrr
  1      9              02022007          chard
  2      9              01022007          exprr
```

I expect that when I take first row of DataFrame 2 , output of Dataframe 1 will be `10='10'` , `01022007 ='01022007' 10='9'`

Need to take one row at a time from Dataframe 2 and replace it in all rows of Dataframe 1.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: when i take first row of DataFrame 2 output of Dataframe 1 will be,  10='10' , 01022007 ='01022007' 10='9'

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Also what is the structure of your dataframes? Is `DF1['Criteria']` a string variable?

Comment: Yes, all values in df['Criteria'] is string